# How to use multi tags/annotations in tests using Playwright

Tags: javascript, annotations, tags, playwright

According to [Playwright Tag-Tests Docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#tag-tests)

Tagging test looks like this:

```
test('My test @foo', async ({ page }) => {
  // ...
});
```

But there is no mention of multi tagging.

I'm looking for something like:

```
test('My test @foo, bar', async ({ page }) => {});
or
test('My test @foo bar', async ({ page }) => {});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, and it's very simple and straight-forward, simply separate tags with space:

```
test('My test @foo @bar', async ({ page }) => {
  // ...
});
```

Execution:

```
// foo OR bar
npx playwright test --grep "@foo|@bar"

// foo AND bar
npx playwright test --grep "(?=.*@foo)(?=.*@bar)"
```

Comment: Have you considered suggesting an update to the docs?

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually yes, I'm still looking into this process, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: This is included in the docs now

Answer (score 0):

Update: As of Playwright v. 1.42, you can now annotate tests by adding a tag object to the test declaration, [paste from the official documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#tag-tests):

```js
test.describe('group', {
  tag: ['@report'],
}, () => {
  test('test full report', {
    tag: ['@slow', '@vrt'],
  }, async ({ page }) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways I am using multi tags

1. grouping my tests in test.describe block and using a tag at that level and then using tag at test level too as following

```
test.describe("Sample test group @smoke @integrations", () => {

  test("Login Test case @regression", async ({
    page,
  }) => {

    // Arrange
    // Act
    
    // Assert
    

  }); // Test case closing

  }); // Test.describe block closing
```

alternatively, the following

2. Use multiple tags in test cases

```
  test("Login Test case @regression @smoke @integrations", async ({
    page,
  }) => {

    // Arrange
    // Act
    
    // Assert
    

  }); // Test case closing
```

and then I use script to run them as following in package.json

```
    "smoke-tests": "npx playwright test --grep @smoke"
```

if you don't want to run it through scripts, you can use the following command in terminal

```
npx playwright test --grep @smoke
```